# Send application to a specific screen using C#

Tags: c#, .net, multiscreen

how could I send an application (think WM_ messages?) which is *not* my application (think: any 3rd party app) to a different screen on a multiscreen system? Is there a specific windows message code I can send to the window or process handle to do this?

Comment: You might edit your question - "not the current application" is confusing.  Do you mean for one application to control another application's location?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. I mean any 3rd party application, not the one I'm writing, hence one that I don't have control over w/ source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use P/Invoke and the [MoveWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MoveWindow.html) function.

**Edit**: It handles multiple screens just fine.  `MoveWindow` sees your screens as one big display, and takes arguments accordingly.  You can use the .Net Screen class to find the bounds of the screen you want, and then call `MoveWindow` to get the window where you want it.

Also, in case you weren't aware of it, there's a good chance that your project is probably going to need the `FindWindowByCaption` function as well.

Comment: I did not know about this one - does it handle multiple screens?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but how about using [WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632631(VS.85).aspx)? The [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) function will allow you to send the required message.  Since you've marked your question as using C#, you'll have to use p/invoke to use it.  Here's an [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/94e500c8-6d1b-43bf-9c04-9823597525bf).

As for getting screen locations and sizes, see the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class in the .Net library.  There's one function called [FromHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromhandle.aspx), and a property called [AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) which returns an array of all the valid screens the user has.  FromHandle() will tell you which screen the app is currently occupying the most (this may or may not be useful in your case).  This will allow you to compute the desired location of the 3rd party application, before sending the message to that application.